# mysql-java-connector connexion denied

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, virtualbox, fedora20

I have a mystery for you.

I am trying to connect to a mysql server on a VM (ip : `192.168.60.96`, runing on my own machine, connected to the network via bridge).

Complete system info :

Host :

```
Fedora 20
Virtualbox 4.3.16
Eclipse 4.3
MySql-connector-java 5.1.33
```

Virtual machine :

```
Debian 6
MySql 5.1.73
```

Pings are OK
PhpMyAdmin run OK

Here is the code I am trying to get to work :

```
/*
 * Cr�� le 24 sept. 2012
 *
 * TODO Pour changer le mod�le de ce fichier g�n�r�, allez � :
 * Fen�tre - Pr�f�rences - Java - Style de code - Mod�les de code
 */
package sec.tests;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TestSgbd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Raccord de m�thode auto-g�n�r�
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.60.96:3306/secolog";
        System.out.println(url);
        try {
            System.out.println("chargement du driver");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("r�cup�ration de la connexion");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"usecolog","password");
            System.out.println("cr�ation d'un statement");
            Statement requete = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("execution d'une requete");
            ResultSet resultat = requete.executeQuery("select * from CLIENT");
            while (resultat.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultat.getString(1)+"  "+resultat.getString(2));
                };
            System.out.println("fin");
            }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

And here is the exception :

```
jdbc:mysql://192.168.60.96:3306/secolog
chargement du driver
r�cup�ration de la connexion
Exception
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'usecolog'@'192.168.60.97' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4332)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1258)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at sec.tests.TestSgbd.main(TestSgbd.java:24)
```

Any idea?

Comment: and i guess your running the vm on your machine?...

Comment: Did you double check your password and database name?

Answer (score 0):

The message says that the user `usecolog` is not allowed to access the databse **from** the host `192.168.60.97`. So you have to give your user in the database the permission to access the database form there (or from anywhere via `%` in the host field. This might be useful when the client has a dynamic IP address via DHCP).

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON secolog.* TO usecolog@'192.168.0.97' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not connecting to wrong IP, the error message is talking about the client:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'usecolog'@'usecolog' (using password: YES)
```

it means that usercolog does not have access to connect to your database from 192.168.60.97 IP. You need to set the priveleges for usercolog to make a connection from your machine IP.

To set the priveleges use this command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON secolog.* TO 'usecolog'@'%192.168.60.97' IDENTIFIED BY 'secologuserpassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: usecolog have the permission to connect from all ip (from '%')

Comment: @Dremor No it does not have the permissions, you may have not flushed the privelges after adding.